# Dilemma, searching a hashed field when no other information is known

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, hash

I'm having a dilemma. I have a field `hashedX` that is a hashed/salted value and the salt is saved in the same row in the mysql database as is common practice.

```
hashedX      saltX
------       ------
hashed1      ssai3
hashed2      woddp
hashed3      92ofu
```

When I receive `inputX`, I need to know if it matches any of the values in `hashedX` such as `hashed1` `hashed2` or `hashed3`. So typically I would take my input, hash/salt it, and compare it to the values of `hashedX`. Pseudo code:

```
$hashed_input = hash ($input with $salt );
select * from tablename where $hashed_input is hashedX
```

The problem is I don't know which `saltX` I need to even get to the `$hashed_input` before I can do any `select`.

I could go through the database rows, one by one, try that salt on my input, then check if the input as hashed/salted with this salt matches `hashedX` of that same row. If I have a 100,000 records, my guess is that this would be painfully slow. I have no idea how slow since I'm not that great at databases.

- Is there a better way to do this, than selecting all rows, looping through them, using that row's salt to hash input, then comparing again to the hashed value in the db?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is possible (depends on your hash formula) define a MySQL `User Defined Function` database side for the `hash` formula (see [CREATE FUNCTION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-function-udf.html)). This way you will be able to get your results in one simple request:

```
SELECT hashedX, saltX FROM tablename WHERE UDFhash(input, saltX) = hashedX ;
```

Comment: Ouch.  That may improve the performance slightly, but it doesn't address the fundamental problem, namely that the complexity of the task is O(N) on table size, defeating the purpose of using a database / hash.

Comment: @slartibartfast: there's no way around it.  It really is a fundamental problem - given that hash algorithms are one-way, O(N) is a firm lower bound on the complexity of any solution to this problem.

Comment: @Borealid: well, there may be ways if we have some restriction on salt value space. Then O(card(salt)) become a possible other lower bound, compatible with an indexed search.

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify which hash algorithm you're using in PHP.  MySQL supports MD5 and SHA1 hash algorithms as [builtin functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/encryption-functions.html):

```
SELECT ...
FROM tablename 
WHERE SHA1(CONCAT(?, saltX)) = hashedX;
```

SHA2 algorithms are supported in MySQL 5.5, but this is only available in pre-beta release at this time.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/news-5-5-x.html for releases.

Comment: In that case, you may need to write a UDF as @kriss suggests.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better way to do this, than selecting all rows, looping
>   through them, using that row's salt to
>   hash input, then comparing again to
>   the hashed value in the db?

Yes.  A much better way.

Typically a salt is only used to prevent exactly what you are trying to do.  So either you don't want to use a salt, or you don't want to do this kind of lookup.

If you are checking an entered password against a given user account or object,  you should reference the object on the same line that you have the salt and hashed salt+password.  Require the account name / object to be referenced when the password is given, then look up the row corresponding to that account name and object and compare the password against that salt + hash.

If you are keeping a record of items that you've seen before, then you should just go with a hash, (or a bloom filter) and forget the salt, because it doesn't buy you anything.

If you're doing something new / creative, please describe what it is.